# What does "Penitential Austerity" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know the separate meanings of the words *penitential* and *austerity*, but what do they actually mean when used together, I'm not a native English speaker, so I have some problem stitching the meaning together.

> No other contemporary poet’s work has such a well-earned reputation for
>   near impenetrability, and there are few whose moral vision is so imperiously unsparing. Of late, however, the almost belligerent demands of his severe (difficult) and densely forbidding poetry have taken an improbable turn. This new collection is the poet’s fourth book in six years — an ample output even for poets of sunny disposition, let alone for one of such **penitential austerity** over the previous 50 years. Yet for all his newfound volubility, his poetry is as thorny as ever.

source:
[The Official Guide to the GRE Revised General Test by ETS](http://greprepclub.com/forum/contemporary-poet-s-work-has-such-a-well-earned-reputation-1930.html)

Comment: We need more context.  Where did you find this?

Comment: Found it in one of the sample questions for GRE. The complete passage can be found [here](http://www.resdi.com/99550/what-does-%26quot-penitential-austerity%26quot-mean-on-hold)

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like a question designed to prevent anyone from achieving 100% on the test.

Comment: the actual question with blanks in the passage : [here](http://greprepclub.com/forum/contemporary-poet-s-work-has-such-a-well-earned-reputation-1930.html)

Comment: That was very helpful.  The paragraph is awful.  I would choose the responses purely by elimination and move on as quickly as possible.

Comment: The answer appears to be C, E and I.

Comment: @ohwilleke, the official answer is C, D, and H.

Answer (score 5):

**Penitential austerity** means that you are depriving yourself of something, a penance for sins that you have committed, as one might do during the season of Lent if one is a liturgical Christian. It is austerity done for the purpose of penance.

Comment: Thanks. So in the edited text above (sorry), is it being used literally or figuratively or in some other sense?

Comment: In the case above: figuratively.